# Is it possible to boost suggestions based on the Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple indices that I want suggestions from, but I want to score/order the suggestions based on the index they're from. I've successfully boosted searches based on indices (using indices_boost), but this doesn't seem to work for suggestions. I tried something like:

```
GET index1,index2/_search
{
  "indices_boost" : [
        { "index1" : 9 },
        { "index2" : 1 }
    ],
  "suggest": {
    "mySuggest":{
      "text":"someText",
      "completion": {
        "field":"suggestField",
        "size":6
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this doable?

At the moment I've resorted to sorting the suggestions in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can try to use category boost in [context suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-suggesters.html#context-suggester) to achieve the desired behavior. You need to attach a special category field to each suggestion document, which can be exactly the same as the index name.

#### How to use `category` context to boost suggestions

The mapping may look like this:

```
PUT food
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
            "suggestField" : {
                "type" : "completion",
                "contexts": [
                    { 
                        "name": "index_name",
                        "type": "category"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For demonstration purposes I will create another index, exactly like the one above but with name `movie`. (Index names can be arbitrary.)

Let's add the suggest documents:

```
PUT food/_doc/1
{
    "suggestField": {
        "input": ["timmy's", "starbucks", "dunkin donuts"],
        "contexts": {
            "index_name": ["food"] 
        }
    }
}

PUT movie/_doc/2
{
    "suggestField": {
        "input": ["star wars"],
        "contexts": {
            "index_name": ["movie"] 
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can run a suggest query with our boosts set:

```
POST food,movie/_search
{
    "suggest": {
        "my_suggestion": {
            "prefix": "star",
            "completion": {
                "field": "suggestField",
                "size": 10,
                "contexts": {
                    "index_name": [
                        {
                            "context": "movie",
                            "boost": 9
                        },
                        {
                            "context": "food",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will return something like this:

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "my_suggestion": [
      {
        "text": "star",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "star wars",
            "_index": "movie",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 9.0,
            "_source": ...,
            "contexts": {
              "index_name": [
                "movie"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "text": "starbucks",
            "_index": "food",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": ...,
            "contexts": {
              "index_name": [
                "food"
              ]
...
```

#### Why didn't `indices_boost` work?

Seems like [`indices_boost`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-index-boost) parameter only affects the search, not suggest. `_suggest` used to be a standalone endpoint, but [was deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-suggesters.html#search-suggesters-api-request), and probably this is the source of confusion.

Hope that helps!